# NSPopupButton binding - distinct display from value

Tags: cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

On my popup button I'm trying to figure out how to get/select via a property of the object.  I have a 'Producer' core data entity, and it has a name (String) and ident (Int) value.  I want to show the name, but get/set the selection based on ident.

What I have right now is that the name shows, but the selection is based on the entire entity object, not just the ident.  How do I make that work?

My NSArrayController is like so:

- Mode: Entity Name
- Entity Name: Producer
- Managed Object Context binding set to the view controller

My NSPopupButton is set like so:

- Content Array: bound to arrangedObjects of Array Controller
- Content Values:

  - Bind to: Array Controller
  - Controller Key: arrangedObjects
  - Model Key Path: name
- Selected Object:

  - Controller Key: empty
  - Model Key Path: producer

Comment: ..did you figure it out?